# Improve Accuracy of Location Manager in iOS Programming

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, dictionary

I am making an application which tracks the user.  I have notice when the application goes in the background and then when you open the app it's shows the wrong current location for the user until about 5 seconds. Is there to fix that because that 5 seconds delay ruins the tracking results ( it's adds three extra miles for no reason ).

Edit: The issue wasn't actually a "bug". I have to set in my Info.plist that I want background pocessing and boom the application tracking is super Accurate. A little tutorial to do that:

1. Go to Info.plist
2. Add an New Row called "Required background modes"
3. Then add again a new row called "App registers for location updates"
4. We are Done :)

Comment: So do you want to update the location in Xcode or in your app? (Hint: of course I know that in your app, but you should not call iOS programming Xcode programming, and you should also omit the xcode tag from questions which are not related to Xcode itself. One does not need Xcode for writing iOS apps.)

Comment: Well what's open is that the app is calculating the user location fine when user closes the app or close iPhone it shows the wrong user location and then after five seconds it shows the right user location and it makes my distance value wrong :(

Comment: @H2CO3 I changed the title to iOS Programming. :)

Comment: How about a +1 for the Edit :)

Comment: I was thinking about it. Here you are to compensate that -1.

Comment: For you too. Enjoy coding and learning.

Comment: H2CO3 I made edits to my older and bad questions could you possible +1 those with good edits. I was banned and told by Stackoverflow Support to edit my old questions I did and nothing happed (still banned :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is check the `horizontalAccuracy` property on the `CLLocation` that you're being returned. If this is above a certain threshold then you could throw away the result and wait for a more accurate one. If it is a number of miles out then I would expect the accuracy figure to be quite large. It's most likely using a cell site to determine location rather than GPS, and the margin of error would be much greater.

In your `CLLocationManagerDelegate`'s `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` method you could do the following:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
  if ([locations count] > 0) {
    CLLocation *lastUpdatedLocation = [locations lastObject];
    CLLocationAccuracy desiredAccuracy = 1000; // 1km accuracy
    if (lastUpdatedLocation.horizontalAccuracy > desiredAccuracy) {
      // This location is inaccurate. Throw it away and wait for the next call to the delegate.
      return;
    } 
    // This is where you do something with your location that's accurate enough.
  }
}
```

Comment: Done. You should really try yourself though.

Comment: Thank You for the code I was wandering on the inaccurate location update should I put in code in it or just ignore it until its gets the accurate location....

Comment: That's up to you. I don't know what's best in terms of your application logic. You said in your question that the inaccurate locations are causing issues, so I would ignore them.

Comment: No, you have to use meters. Check the documentation here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocationDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLLocationAccuracy

Comment: Thanks for the code but I noticed the so called "bug" was actually only happening in the background. So I made my app support background processing.